# Ember.js - List values from store

Tags: javascript, ember.js

From a route or component, I want to create an array of values from store data.  E.g. I have a project model and I want to get a list of project names i can use in select boxes, table headings...

I've tried the following and looked at computed properties, but can't get this working?

```
// user route

model() {

    let projects = this.store.findAll('project').then((projects) => {
        return projects.mapBy('name');
    });

    ...
```

---

Update:

```
// users.new route
import Ember from 'ember';

export
default Ember.Route.extend({

    projectNames: [],

    afterModel: function () {
        this._super(...arguments);
        return this.store.findAll('project').then((projects) => {
            this.set('projectNames', projects.mapBy('name'));
        });
    },

    setupController: function (controller) {
        this._super(...arguments);
        controller.set('projectNames', this.get('projectNames'));
    },

    model() {
        let user = this.store.createRecord('user'),
            projectRoles = [],
            projects = this.get('projectNames');

            console.log('projectNames: ' + this.get('projectNames'));

        projects.forEach((project) => {
            let projectRole = this.store.createRecord('projectRole', {
                project: project,
                role: 'Viewer'
            });
            projectRoles.push(projectRole);
        });

        // Create 1 role per project
        Ember.RSVP.all(projectRoles.map(projectRole => projectRole.save())).then((projectRoles) => {
            user.set('projectRoles', projectRoles);
        });

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks ok, so far. Can you show the rest of the code of your route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basics of what you need can be answered with the `beforeModel()` hook. The `beforeModel()` hook returns a promise, which will be fulfilled before the `model()` hook will be called. That lets you load the list of projects first. The following code (untested) should get you there:

```
// services/project-core.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  projects: null,

  init() {
    this.set('projects', []);
  },

  // getProjects() needs to be called at least once before the projects are available in the application. Ideally this method will be called in the route's beforeModel() hook.
  getProjects() {
    if (this.get('projects').length === 0 {
      // this makes sure we only query for the projects once; you may not want this block. I personally like to avoid unneeded queries.
      return this.get('store').findAll('project').then(projects => {
        this.set('projects', projects);
      });
    } else {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({});
    }
  }
});
```

and your route, with some changes:

```
// users.new route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  projectCore: Ember.inject.service(),

  beforeModel() {
    return this.get('projectCore').getProjects();
  },

  model() {

    // Here you'll be able to do things like:
    this.set('projectNames', this.store.peekAll('project').map(function(x) {return x.get('name')}));

    // and from your code:
    let user = this.store.createRecord('user'),
        projectRoles = [],
        projects = this.get('projectNames');

    console.log('projectNames: ' + this.get('projectNames'));

    projects.forEach((project) => {
      let projectRole = this.store.createRecord('projectRole', {
          project: project,
          role: 'Viewer'
      });
      projectRoles.push(projectRole);
    });

    // and so on...
  }
}
```

If you want to use the projects in your template, you can just use them like so:

```
<ul>
  {{#each projectCore.projects as |project|}}
    <li>{{project.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and if you want the `projectNames` array available, remember to use `setupController` as you did in your question.

In fact, in my experience you probably rarely want to use the `projectNames` array, but instead are better off iterating through the set of projects. This is particularly true in templates.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this.  This solution works great!

Answer (score 3):

It isn't working because you need to return a promise object from the `model` method of the route.

```
// return a promise object from the model.
// This is available as the `model` property in the route's controller
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('project')
},

// Store the list of names in a property ('projectNames') on the route's
// controller.
setupController(controller, models) {
  controller.set('projectNames', models.mapBy('name'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gnerkus that works and i can loop over the items in the template, but i want to work with this array in a route.  When i try `this.controllerFor('users.new').get('projectNames'))` it returns undefined?  Accessing another property in this way works fine

Comment: This code is for the route so you can access the 'projectNames' via `this.get('projectNames')`.

Comment: Hmm, tried that, but no joy.  I've added my route above.  Accessing another property works okay?

Comment: I've just been fighting with something similar recently, and what I've been arriving at is that maybe this behaviour doesn't belong in a route? Perhaps you need a service that will supply the project names wherever you need them? Then use the `beforeModel()` hook (which returns a promise) to make sure the project names are available to your route. If this approach makes sense and feels relevant to you, I'd be happy to think through a proper answer.

Comment: @pauldoerwald thanks for responding.  That makes sense to me.  If you come up with anything would appreciate you sharing and i'll do likewise.

Comment: For posterity: you don't have to return a promise, you can return an object, array, or promise that will resolve into an object or array. One nice thing about the `model()` hook is that the promise is guaranteed to resolve prior to the next step in the lifecycle.